# How can I combine or simplify many different methods that differ just by one string in what they do?

Tags: c#

My application has many methods that are similar except for one word. Here I am showing just two of them.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could optimize this code without just changing to a method that accepts a string. Or if I do that then I need some way to check the string is valid.  The reason I would like not to accept a string is that if someone types in an incorrect spelling of the string then it would lead to problems:

```
    public static Frame GetFrameWithArrow()
    {

        var SVG = new SvgCachedImage()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        SVG.SetDynamicResource(SvgCachedImage.SourceProperty, "RightArrowIcon");

        var FR = new Frame()
        {
            Content = SVG,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HasShadow = false,
            Padding = new Thickness(9),
        };
        FR.SetDynamicResource(Frame.WidthRequestProperty, "SVGIconWidthRequest");

        return FR;
    }

    public static Frame GetFrameWithTick()
    {

        var SVG = new SvgCachedImage()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        SVG.SetDynamicResource(SvgCachedImage.SourceProperty, "TickIcon");

        var FR = new Frame()
        {
            Content = SVG,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HasShadow = false,
            Padding = new Thickness(9),
        };
        FR.SetDynamicResource(Frame.WidthRequestProperty, "SVGIconWidthRequest");

        return FR;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a private method with parameters called by each of the public ones such as `GetFrame("RightArrowIcon");` called by `GetFrameWithArrow()`.

The public part will remain the same

```
// private common part here
private static Frame GetFrame(string IconName)
{
    var SVG = new SvgCachedImage()
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    };
    // check this ----------------------------------------v------v
    SVG.SetDynamicResource(SvgCachedImage.SourceProperty, IconName);

    var FR = new Frame()
    {
        Content = SVG,
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HasShadow = false,
        Padding = new Thickness(9),
    };
    FR.SetDynamicResource(Frame.WidthRequestProperty, "SVGIconWidthRequest");

    return FR;
}

// public parts, unchanged signature for your callers
public static Frame GetFrameWithArrow()
{
    return GetFrame("RightArrowIcon");
}

public static Frame GetFrameWithTick()
{
    return GetFrame("TickIcon");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method which accepts the string and validates if string is part of allowed list which are accepted by your application.

```
private List<string> allowedSources = new List<string>() { "RightArrowIcon", "TickIcon" /* populated the allowed string here */ };
private static Frame GetFrame(string sourceIcon)
{
    if (!allowedSources.Contains(source)) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("your message here");
    }
    
    var SVG = new SvgCachedImage()
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    };
    SVG.SetDynamicResource(SvgCachedImage.SourceProperty, sourceIcon);

    var FR = new Frame()
    {
        Content = SVG,
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HasShadow = false,
        Padding = new Thickness(9),
    };
    FR.SetDynamicResource(Frame.WidthRequestProperty, "SVGIconWidthRequest");

    return FR;
}
```

Now the other method can call this private method like

```
public static Frame GetFrameWithArrow()
{
    return GetFrame("RightArrowIcon");
}

public static Frame GetFrameWithTick()
{
    return GetFrame("TickIcon");
}
```

Comment: is `allowedSources` really needed? The method is private, only the interface will call it

Comment: So mentioned `Or if I do that then I need some way to check the string is valid` so added a collection to validate if input parameter is valid or not.

Comment: I would validate the input only if the user can call the method `GetFrame()`